# Advice on how to do queue system for network requests (when with poor connectivity)

Tags: android

I've been building a network requests Queue class for cases where network connectivity may fail temporarily to come back online later. The end goal is every time network connection fails, the request gets queued until the network is available again.

Here's the code done so far for sending data:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;

import construction.site.logistics.foreman.Encryption.Encryption;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.Fragments.FragmentJournal;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.MainActivity;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.R;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.abstraction.Functions;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.data.database.EntityFields;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.data.database.EntityFiles;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.data.database.EntityQueue;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.data.database.LocalDatabaseOperations;
import construction.site.logistics.foreman.data.state;


public class SendData  {

    private Activity activity=null;
private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity=null;

private EntityQueue queue=null;
private List<EntityFields> fieldsInList=null;
private List<EntityFiles> filesInList=null;

private Boolean encrypt;
private String encryptionType="";
private Boolean waitForCode=false;
private Boolean loadMainPage=false;
private Boolean enableQueue=true;
private Integer retryCount;
private String title;

private static Boolean error;
private String responseMsg;
public ObservableValue DelayedResult;

public SendData (Activity _activity, FragmentActivity _fragmentActivity){
    this.activity=_activity;
    this.fragmentActivity=_fragmentActivity;
    this.DelayedResult = new ObservableValue(getResponse());
    this.retryCount=0;
}

public void setWaitForCode(Boolean _wait){ waitForCode=_wait;}
public void setloadMainPage(Boolean _load){ loadMainPage=_load;}
public String getResponse(){ return responseMsg; }
public Boolean getError(){ return error; }

public void addQueue(EntityQueue _queue){ queue=_queue;}
public void addFields(List<EntityFields> _fields){ fieldsInList=_fields;}
public void addfFiles(List<EntityFiles> _files){ filesInList=_files;}

public void setEnableQueue(Boolean _queue){ enableQueue=_queue; }
public void setEncryption(Boolean _encrypt, String _type){
    encryptionType= _type;
    encrypt=_encrypt;
}


public class ObservableValue extends Observable
{
    private String responseMsg = "";
    public ObservableValue(String _responseMsg)
    {
        this.responseMsg = _responseMsg;
    }
    public void setValue(String _responseMsg)
    {
        this.responseMsg = _responseMsg;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
    public String getValue()
    {
        return responseMsg;
    }
}

public boolean send(){
    error=false;
    if (waitForCode) {
        try{
            SendDataAsync sendDataAsync =new SendDataAsync();
            sendDataAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).get();
            error=false;
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Functions.SaveCrash(e, activity);
            error=true;
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        SendDataAsync sendDataAsync =new SendDataAsync();
        sendDataAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        error=false;
        return true;
    }
}

private class SendDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        error=true;
        if (queue == null) {
            responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_missing_queue) + "'}";
        } else if (fieldsInList == null) {
            responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_missing_fields) + "'}";
        } else if (state.getNetworkStatus()) { // send immediately
            //Json format var="{'error':true,'message':'some message'}";
            String Data2Send = "{";
            String temp = "";

            JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();
            List<String> FileNamesList= new ArrayList<>();
            FileNamesList.clear();
            Data2Send = "";

            EntityFields field = new EntityFields();
            field.setRequestVar("tid");
            field.setValue(state.serial);
            fieldsInList.add(field);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldsInList.size(); i++) {
                    jObjectData.put(fieldsInList.get(i).getRequestVar(), fieldsInList.get(i).getValue().replace("'", "\'").replace('"', '\"'));
                }

                if (filesInList != null) {
                    temp = "";
                    String temp2 = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < filesInList.size(); i++) {
                        FileNamesList.add(filesInList.get(i).getFilename());
                        temp2 += filesInList.get(i).getAppendCode() ? "1" : "0";
                        temp += i == 0 ? temp2 : "," + temp2;
                    }
                    jObjectData.put("filecode", temp);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Functions.SaveCrash(e, activity);
            }
            Data2Send = jObjectData.toString();

            Encryption encryption = new Encryption(activity);
            encryption.setSecretKey(state.encryptionKey);
            if (encryption.encryptString(Data2Send)) {
                HttpComm request = new HttpComm(activity);
                request.setType("post");
                request.setCharSet("UTF-8");
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Functions.showSimpleProgressDialog(activity, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_connect_title_msg), activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_connect_msg),false);
                    }
                });
                String urlEncoded="";
                try{
                    urlEncoded=URLEncoder.encode(encryption.getEncryptedString(), "UTF-8");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    urlEncoded=encryption.getEncryptedString();
                }
                error = !request.send(queue.getUrl(), urlEncoded, FileNamesList);
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Functions.removeSimpleProgressDialog();
                    }
                });

                if(queue.getMsgError().equals("debug")) {
                    encryption.decryptString(request.getResponse());
                    responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'DEBUG: " + encryption.getDecryptedString() + "'}";
                }else if(error && retryCount< 6){
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    activity.setTitle(R.string.commServer_retry+" "+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    activity.setTitle(title);
                                    retryCount++;
                                    send();
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
                    return "retrying";
                }else if (error && enableQueue) {
                    LocalDatabaseOperations localDatabaseOperations = new LocalDatabaseOperations(activity);
                    error = LocalDatabaseOperations.addQueue(queue, fieldsInList, filesInList);
                    if (error) {
                        responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + request.getMessage() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + localDatabaseOperations.getErrMessage() + "'}";
                    } else {
                        responseMsg = "{'error':false,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_added_queue) + "'}";
                    }
                } else if (error && !enableQueue) {
                    responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + request.getMessage() + "'}";
                } else { // success sending request
                    if (encryption.decryptString(request.getResponse())) {
                        if (encryption.getEncryptedVector().equals(encryption.getDecryptedVector())) {
                            responseMsg = encryption.getDecryptedString(); // success on retrieving data from server
                        } else {
                            String ss=encryption.getEncryptedVector();
                            String sss=encryption.getDecryptedVector();
                            String s=encryption.getDecryptedString();
                            responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_error_ivector) + "'}";
                        }
                    } else { // error decrypting string
                        responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_error_decrypt_data) + "'}";
                        String response= request.getResponse();
                        String str= "Message:"+encryption.getErrMessage()+"  >>>>Encrypt:"+ encryption.getEncryptedVector()+"  >>>>Dencrypt:"+ encryption.getDecryptedVector();
                        Exception e= new Exception(str);
                        Functions.SaveCrash(e, activity);
                    }
                }
            } else { // error encrypting string
                responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_error_encrypt_data) + "'}";
            }
        }else if(!enableQueue){
            responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.error_no_network)  + "'}";
        } else { // send to queue
            LocalDatabaseOperations localDatabaseOperations = new LocalDatabaseOperations(activity);
            error = LocalDatabaseOperations.addQueue(queue, fieldsInList, filesInList);
            if (error) {
                responseMsg = "{'error':true,'message':'" + localDatabaseOperations.getErrMessage() + "'}";
            } else {
                responseMsg = "{'error':false,'message':'" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sendData_added_queue) + "'}";
            }
        }
        return responseMsg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response.equals("retrying")){
            return;
        }
        DelayedResult.setValue(response);

        if (queue.getMsgType().equals("toast")) {
            if (Functions.isSuccess(response)) {
                if (queue.getMsgSuccess().equals("") || queue.getMsgSuccess().equals("response")) {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, Functions.getErrorCode(activity, response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, queue.getMsgSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (queue.getMsgError().equals("") || queue.getMsgError().equals("response")) {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, Functions.getErrorCode(activity, response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, queue.getMsgError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else if (queue.getMsgType().equals("alertbox")) { // alertbox
            if (Functions.isSuccess(response)) {
                if (queue.getMsgSuccess().equals("") || queue.getMsgSuccess().equals("response")) {activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Functions.alertbox(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_submit_ok), Functions.getErrorCode(activity, response), activity);
                    }
                });

                } else {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Functions.alertbox(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_submit_ok), queue.getMsgSuccess(), activity);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (queue.getMsgError().equals("") || queue.getMsgError().equals("response") || queue.getMsgError().equals("debug")) {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Functions.alertbox(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_submit_error), Functions.getErrorCode(activity, response), activity);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Functions.alertbox(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.commServer_submit_error), queue.getMsgError(), activity);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        // Show messageBox messages
        if (Functions.hasMessageBox(response)) {
            Functions.getMessageBox(response);
        }

        if (loadMainPage && !error) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentJournal());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

where the following code

```
LocalDatabaseOperations localDatabaseOperations = new LocalDatabaseOperations(activity);
error = LocalDatabaseOperations.addQueue(queue, fieldsInList, filesInList);
```

is for storing data in local device SQL server in a common SQL table using Room database. Next i have a listener listening for networks changes that triggers, on successful network connectivity, sending the data request again.